# Spring boot security configuration not working properly with roles/authorities

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I have a problem with Spring Boot. The security configuration is not working.

The `configure` method looks like this:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .cors()
            .and()
            .csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(ApplicationConstants.API_PREFIX + "/authenticate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(ApplicationConstants.API_PREFIX + "/register").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(ApplicationConstants.API_PREFIX + "/activate").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(ApplicationConstants.API_PREFIX + "/consentTypes").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(ApplicationConstants.API_PREFIX + "/**").fullyAuthenticated()
            .antMatchers(ApplicationConstants.API_PREFIX + "/onboard/**", "/user/me").hasAnyAuthority(ApplicationConstants.USER, ApplicationConstants.ADMIN, ApplicationConstants.SUPER_ADMIN)
            .antMatchers(ApplicationConstants.API_PREFIX + "/consentType/**",  "/consentType").hasAnyAuthority(ApplicationConstants.ADMIN, ApplicationConstants.SUPER_ADMIN)
            .antMatchers(ApplicationConstants.API_PREFIX + "/register/admin").hasAnyAuthority(ApplicationConstants.ADMIN, ApplicationConstants.SUPER_ADMIN)
            .antMatchers(ApplicationConstants.API_PREFIX + "/user/all").hasAnyAuthority(ApplicationConstants.ADMIN, ApplicationConstants.SUPER_ADMIN)
            .antMatchers(ApplicationConstants.API_PREFIX + "/register/superAdmin").hasAuthority(ApplicationConstants.SUPER_ADMIN)
            .and()
            .addFilter(new JwtAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager(), tokenProvider)).antMatcher("/**")
            .sessionManagement()
            .sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}
```

The `ApplicationConstants` class looks like this:

```
public class ApplicationConstants {

    public static final String API_PREFIX = "/api/v1";
    public static final String SPRING_PROFILE_TEST = "test";
    public static final String SPRING_PROFILE_DEV = "dev";

    public static final String USER = "USER";
    public static final String ADMIN = "ADMIN";
    public static final String SUPER_ADMIN = "SUPER_ADMIN";

    private ApplicationConstants() {
    }
}
```

This configuration somehow allows an `USER` to, for example, create new consent types, which it shouldn't, get all users (`/user/all`) which operation should't be accesible for him.

I have tried a few things, I have prefixed the authority constants with `ROLE_`, I've tried out many combinations of `antMatcher` patterns etc. Nothing is even helping. What could I done wrong? The security is JWT-based, it seems to provide the role names correctly. It was adding a `ROLE_` prefix by its own, so I have deleted the prefix from constants, nothing.

Comment: Ordering is important. Basically everything after the `/**` mapping in your list isn't used. The rules are consulted in the order they are defined in so the `/**` mapping (the catch all!) must always be last.

Comment: @M.Deinum Your soultion has solved my problem! Thanks!